# How to convert a date from nvarchar in irregular format

Tags: date-formatting

I am trying to convert a date from a format that is irregular. It is an nvarchar(20) with dates and times shown as

26-10-2006 11:38

6-11-2006 9:39

8-9-2005 14:13

Is it possible to extract the date part?

Comment: and the language is.....?  SQL

Comment: `to_char(to_date('26-10-2006 11:38', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')` in case of *Oracle*

Comment: Very few things are *impossible*, and your problem is not among them. However, in order to have a *solution*, please, provide *relevant info* for us — language (*Oracle*?), all possible inputs (what do you mean by *irregular*?) your tries and fails.

Comment: Sorry, it is SQL Server. By irregular I mean that month and date can be both mm and m and dd and d
Furthermore, convert(datetime) havent gotten me anywhere and I cant figure out a systematic way to extract the dates

Comment: Okay, found a solution with a convert function

convert(datetime,VAR, 103) 

Which worked. Some of the ofter formats I tried didn't work. 
Sorry for the inconvenience.